# Heroku - Extremely slow put request update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple blog application that I put up on Heroku's free 5gb space. When I send get requests and post requests the response time is snappy and I get a response.

The same thing happens with my put requests (standard 302 redirect as specified in my application, works perfectly on my local server). However, **my pages don't update with the new information until minutes, sometimes many minutes (~10 - 20 mins) later on the actual page.**

**Update** I took a look into my heroku rails console and it seems that the information is updated there. I believe **it might be a browser/cache issue, but I'm not quite sure why?**

I'm not quite sure why this is happening. Here is my update code in my Article controller.

```
def update
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
    if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
      format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Article was successfully updated.') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @article.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

As requested, here is the PUT request portion of my tail log.

```
2013-06-19T01:13:01.124408+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/articles/5-Literary-
 Compositions-" for 99.232.11.181 at 2013-06-19 01:13:01 +0000

2013-06-19T01:13:01.445438+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/articles/5-
 Literary-Compositions- host=hidden-taiga-5779.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.11.181" dyno=web.1 
connect=2ms service=516ms status=302 bytes=138


2013-06-19T01:13:01.443470+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ArticlesController#update as HTML

2013-06-19T01:13:01.443470+00:00 app[web.1]:  #post information was in here, large post


2013-06-19T01:13:01.443470+00:00 app[web.1]: 
Redirected to http://hidden-taiga-5779.herokuapp.com/articles/5-Literary-Compositions-


2013-06-19T01:13:01.443470+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 279ms (ActiveRecord: 71.2ms)
```

Comment: Can you show the Heroku logs. Run `heroku logs` this will show you what potentially could be happening. From the looks of it I don't see why any problem with your `update` method.

Comment: updated the original post

Comment: Maybe this is a browser or cache issue? In my heroku rails console the information is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to add to your answer, but I believe you can have `cache_action :show` on your controller, its just a matter of setting this up correctly. I did notice [Building a Rails 3 Application with Memcache](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-rails-3-application-with-memcache). Not sure if you took a read of this but this shows you how to set your application up with the heroku MemCachier Add-on. As the [installation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-rails-3-application-with-memcache#install-the-memcachier-add-on-and-configure-caching) will take you through exactly what you need to know. But something does tell me that you may not have installed the Memcahcier add-on and configured it. If you didn't do this then by all means put `cached_action :show` back into your blog_controller and install the add-on and inspect result of this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into adding it back. After reading the article it sounds like adding in the add-on should relieve the aforementioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that in the blog controller was a line:

```
cached_action :show
```

From the documents [ActionController](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html.)

> Action caching is similar to page caching by the fact that the entire output of the response is cached, but unlike page caching, every request still goes through Action Pack. The key benefit of this is that filters run before the cache is served, which allows for authentication and other restrictions on whether someone is allowed to execute such action.

I've taken it out and it works fine again. Thanks for the help. Hopefully this post helps someone else as well.